# Fastest way to convert SqlDataReader to list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, optimization

I try to get a lot of data from a SQL Server database using C#. I get something like 300K rows of data from the database (I believe it's not far from the worst case that can be.) that can contain hundreds of millions.

I don't think the problem it's about the size of the database because
of the `command.ExecuteReader();` takes about nothing and less than a second.

I tried this code:

```
public List<ResultPulser> GetReportResult(SqlConnection opCon, SqlCommand command,
    int minReport,int maxReport,int machineNumber)
{
    List<ResultPulser> results = new List<ResultPulser>();

    using (DataContext dc = new DataContext(opCon))
    {
        try
        {
            command.CommandText = "select * from ResultPulser " +
                "where CAST(SUBSTRING([ReportNumber], 0, 8) as int) = @machineNumber and " +
                "CAST(SUBSTRING([ReportNumber],8,LEN([ReportNumber])) as int) BETWEEN @minReport AND @maxReport";
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minReport", minReport);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxReport", maxReport);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineNumber", machineNumber);

            Stopwatch SW1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            SW1.Stop();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            Stopwatch SW2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            table.Load(reader);
            SW2.Stop();

            Stopwatch SW3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            ResultPulser[] report = new ResultPulser[table.Rows.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.Rows[i];
                report[i] = new ResultPulser(Convert.ToInt64(dr[0]), dr[1].ToString().Trim(),
                    dr[2].ToString().Trim(), Convert.ToDateTime(dr[3]), Convert.ToDouble(dr[4]),
                    Convert.ToDouble(dr[5]), Convert.ToDouble(dr[6]), Convert.ToDouble(dr[7]),
                    Convert.ToDouble(dr[8]), Convert.ToDouble(dr[9]), Convert.ToInt64(dr[10]),
                    Convert.ToInt64(dr[11]), Convert.ToInt64(dr[12]), Convert.ToBoolean(dr[13]),
                    Convert.ToInt32(dr[14]));
            }
            SW3.Stop();

            reader.Close();
            return report.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LocalPulserDBManagerInstance.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

But the next line `table.Load(reader);`  takes about 20 seconds to complete.

I also tried like this:

```
public List<ResultPulser> GetReportResult(SqlConnection opCon, SqlCommand command,
            int minReport,int maxReport,int machineNumber)
{
            List<ResultPulser> results = new List<ResultPulser>();

            using (DataContext dc = new DataContext(opCon))
            {
                try
                {
                    command.CommandText = "select * from ResultPulser " +
                        "where CAST(SUBSTRING([ReportNumber], 0, 8) as int) = @machineNumber and " +
                        "CAST(SUBSTRING([ReportNumber],8,LEN([ReportNumber])) as int) BETWEEN @minReport AND @maxReport";
                    command.Parameters.Clear();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minReport", minReport);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxReport", maxReport);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineNumber", machineNumber);

                    Stopwatch SW1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    SW1.Stop();

                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    Stopwatch SW2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        results.Add(new ResultPulser(reader.GetInt64(0), reader.GetString(1).Trim(), reader.GetString(2).Trim(),
                            reader.GetDateTime(3), reader.GetDouble(4), reader.GetDouble(5), reader.GetDouble(6),
                            reader.GetDouble(7), reader.GetDouble(8), reader.GetDouble(9), reader.GetInt64(10),
                            reader.GetInt64(11), reader.GetInt64(12), reader.GetBoolean(13), reader.GetInt32(14)));
                    }
                    SW2.Stop();


                    reader.Close();
                    return results;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LocalPulserDBManagerInstance.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
 }
```

In this case, this code part takes about 17-16 seconds...

```
  while (reader.Read())
  {
      results.Add(new ResultPulser(reader.GetInt64(0), reader.GetString(1).Trim(), reader.GetString(2).Trim(),
                            reader.GetDateTime(3), reader.GetDouble(4), reader.GetDouble(5), reader.GetDouble(6),
                            reader.GetDouble(7), reader.GetDouble(8), reader.GetDouble(9), reader.GetInt64(10),
                            reader.GetInt64(11), reader.GetInt64(12), reader.GetBoolean(13), reader.GetInt32(14)));
                    }
```

How can I optimize my code to do it faster than that?

Comment: And what will you do with your list of 300,000 objects once you have created it?

Comment: Incidentally, your query performance might improve somewhat if you indexed and didn't manipulate the column you search - saying `WHERE reportnumber BETWEEN @min AND @max` where @min is eg `01234567000123` and @max is `01234567000789` and making the parameters fit the data is always better than making the data fit the parameters every time you query; the db has enough to do returning 300000 data items to you without the load of 600000 substring and 600000 integer conversions too, and as noted manipulating the column kills any chance of using an index

Comment: The first question, as Caius says above, is really, do you need to load that much data into memory in one go? And if the answer is yes, then it is going to take real measurable time to transfer that much data into you program.

Comment: `reader.GetString(1).Trim()` -> you can't store the string as a `varchar` or `nvarchar` and trim it at insert time? While this won't take a huge amount of time, not doing it will save time.

Comment: Indeed, I ask 'cos if the answer is "I'm going to put them in a ComboBox and let the user pick one!" then you need to review your UI/UX requirements. If it's "I'm going to write them to disk/send them down a socket" then the answer is to stream them directly, one at a time rather than load them into memory. There are very few good reasons to have such a massive set of data in memory. If every object is one kb it's 300meg plus just for the list. Also, do you know list uses a size 16 array internally and doubles it(copying every element) when it needs more space? Millions of useless copy ops..

Comment: @CaiusJard  well...  I think Its better way to do the minimum queries that I can so I did it in one query

And yes I have to get all the data from there... and Create a Excel report from that

Using Excel Interop

Comment: That's ludicrous. You already said the query is fast; implement the improvement I recommended so you aren't crippling the index on reportnumber, make sure there IS an index on report number and query the db often for the small items of data you need. Don't download 300,000 items just because you might need a few thousand of them and don't want to make a hundred db queries. Consider also what your user will do with his 300,000 line report; summarize it probably, because who wants to/can look at 300,000 lines of data and make sense of it. This whole thing is a half baked XY problem..

Comment: (And consider that, in the context it's going to take your user minutes or hours to review 300,000 lines, 7 seconds to generate the data is a drop in the ocean. Save server resources and write them to file one by one; you don't need all this in memory. If you're summarizing the data in the c#, summarize it in the db using SQL instead so X hundred megabytes doesn't travel across the network - likely the the slowest part)

Comment: @CaiusJard, In short, you say that ther is no way to make it faster and the best solution is to select fewer rows and find  a way to do it?

Comment: `ExecuteReader()` does not actually execute the query, it merley prepares it. `while (reader.Read())` does the actual work, both on the SQL server and the network.

Comment: When I do the query outside the code on Visual Studio UI Its give me all data and do it really fast

Comment: *do it really fast* - it might be showing you the first 30 rows really fast, but... I'm more saying that your approach to the problem is wrong; either trying to save this 17 seconds is a useless micro-optimization and you should be focusing on minimizing impact on server resources (for which I've already suggested indexing/sargability and batch/incremental writing rather than all-in-memory) or you're dragging far too much data out of the database for what the ultimate solution will be (for which I've already suggested SQL based sumamrization). Review the requirements of the project/work item

Comment: I think when you load 300,000 rows in one thread, and load it in memory, when all in table or adding them in while loop in second solution which you've mentioned, you won't see significant performance. It's better to change query style and partition 300K rows into more little fetches, for example 6*50k or 10*30, and handle them in 6 or 10 threads. In that way you might see great performance

Comment: Why not use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)? It's free and nasty fast

Comment: [Here's how the c# code would look with Dapper.](https://rextester.com/RZDVU19485)

Comment: @ZoharPeled   it is even Slower...

Comment: It might be slower but the code will be far more readable and maintainable which most of the time is more important. The slowness is probably not on the c# side anyway but on the SQL side, as demonstrated by the answer you've received.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
"where CAST(SUBSTRING([ReportNumber], 0, 8) as int) = @machineNumber and " +
"CAST(SUBSTRING([ReportNumber],8,LEN([ReportNumber])) as int) BETWEEN @minReport AND @maxReport";
```

By using these `CAST(SUBSTRING(...))` expressions you're forcing full scan on this (presumably large) table.
You need to change it/optimize it so that it contains bare column names in WHERE.

What I assume from the predicates the ReportNumber column has values of the form
MMMMMMMMR+
where `MMMMMMMM` is the machine number and `R+` is one or more digits of the report number.

I'm not sure what is the data type of the ReportNumber column. It can be a `bigint` or some kind of string. From the query it seems it's a string, but you might as well use implicit conversions.

Anyway there's great potential to optimize this and bring it to elapsed time measured in single milliseconds.

I can only give you a starting point as there's not enough info.

The first part is easy:

```sql
"where CAST(SUBSTRING([ReportNumber], 0, 8) as int) = @machineNumber"
```

becomes

```sql
"where ReportNumber LIKE @machineNumber"
```

so this becomes a prefix search, and you change the C# part to pass the parameter as a prefix search for LIKE:

```cs
string machineNumberLikeString = machineNumber.ToString() + "%";
```

then pass it to the query like so:

```cs
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineNumber", machineNumberLikeString);
```

Then on the SQL side you can create an index to support fast searching data for this query (but only if it's used quite often - which is a subjective and depending on your workload and requirements). Remember that indexes have their cost and the gain must outweigh it.

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX_ResultPulser_ReportNumber
    ON ResultPulser (ReportNumber);
```

It will work assuming the column ReportNumber is of some string data type, e.g. VARCHAR or NVARCHAR. If it's numeric, it may or may not work. A modified strategy is required. But I'm out of time and I don't have enough info on the data and the table.

EDIT: It may not help if you're extracting 300 thousand rows in one query. SQL Server would need 300k lookups to fetch remaining columns for your `SELECT *`. You may consider clustering this table on ReportNumber columns (CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX...).

And the last warning: do not use `SELECT *` (select star) in production code. Always explicitly specify which columns you require.

Hope that this will help you.